# Why website can have two ip addresses?

Tags: dns, centos, ip, hosts-file

For example, `host github.com` prints two ip addresses as below.

```
>>> host github.com
github.com has address 192.30.253.112
github.com has address 192.30.253.113
...
```

1. Why can it have two addresses?
2. On CentOS, how can I force the system to use one address rather than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why it can have two addresses?

Why not? People use multiple addresses for load balancing all the time.

> For CentOS, How to force system to use 192.30.253.112 instead of 192.30.253.113?

You can simply put a static entry in `/etc/hosts` - but don't forget about it in case github changes the IPs.

Comment: Github has many ips. Why I only see those two with host command?

Comment: That's not easy to say - I see only `192.30.253.112` currently. Possibly they're using anycasting.